# UIScrollView random point

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, cgpoint, arc4random

I'm making a game and want it so that a picture spawns randomly every second somewhere on a scroll view. The scroll view size is `320x960`, and I have it so that the picture gets its point using `arc4random()`. However, even when I get a `y` value of say, `900`, the picture doesn't spawn on that point of the scroll view. This is my code

```
- (void)gift1 {
    UIImage *image7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gift.png"];
    gift = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image7];
    CGRect rect7 = CGRectMake(arc4random()%320, random()% 960 + 0, 100, 100);
    gift.frame = rect7;
    [scrollView addSubview:gift];
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(self.myAnimatedView.frame, self.gift.frame)) {
        [self giftg];
    }
    NSLog(@"%f", self.gift.frame.origin.y);
}
```

Comment: @n9986 it spawns them only on the first picture of the scroll view and by the way the scroll view scrolls vertically